# After installing mssql driver, I get driver not found exception in php (MAC OS 10.11.3)

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

My php version is 7.1. I installed mssql driver and other  sqlsrv,pdo_sqlsrv drivers. But when I try this,

```
 #php artisan migrate
```

I get  following exception

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and n  
  ame = migrations)                                                            



  [PDOException]         
  could not find driver
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem,

I found out that the cli was using php7.1 but I did follow the MS Guide for installing the SqlServer driver for php 7.0.

For some reason, php was using 7.0 and the cli was using 7.1.

So my routes were working (when querying sql server), but the `php artisan migrate` gave that error.

For my specific case, I resolved by removing php 7.1, leaving only the 7.0 for php and php-cli.

```
apt-get purge php7.1-common
```

This answer pointed me in the right direction

[Laravel SQL Server - PDOException could not find driver on migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376698/laravel-sql-server-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-on-migrate)

Good luck :)

Comment: thank you. But I gave up after struggling 3/4 days with environment issue(php7.1+mssql+MAC). Using docker for development now:(